# Removing gaps in left and right sides of flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this flex container which contains the left box, center box, and right box.

I applied the flex-start in alignment to rearrange blocks from position 3 to position 3 and from position 1 to position 2 while the center box consisting of the image moves to position 1 in the column.

Initially, this is meant for mobile version layout.  The header above the flex container has an absolutely positioned off-canvas menu toggle button placed on the right and has the height set to auto.

After applying the code I found the mobile layout showing strange gaps in the left side next to the left box and the right side next to the right box.

Assuming the left box and right box have the absolute positioning to accommodate complex placement of elements in desktop version (i.e. overlapping web 3.0 style contemporary blocks), where there is a margin-left applied to both left box and right box because of absolute position, I thought that flex-start property would remove gaps in left and right sides of screen (which are like "ghost gaps").

Ideally, I want the left box and right box or entire container along with header sticks to the left and right sides of the screen.

Here is a bit pseudocode for reference:

```
HEADER
         header{height: auto;}

CONTAINER
         .container{width:750px; margin:auto; background: white: 
   padding: 15px;}

ROW (containing three boxes)
             .row{clear:both;
               width:750px;
               display: -webkit-box;
              display: -moz-box;
              display: -ms-flexbox;
              display: -webkit-flex;
             display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
           -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
           -moz-box-orient: vertical;
           -webkit-flex-direction: column;
          -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
           /* optional */
         -webkit-box-align: start;
           -moz-box-align: start;
          -ms-flex-align: start;
        -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
        align-items: flex-start;}

LEFT BOX
         #leftabout{
         -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
         -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
         -ms-flex-order: 2;
         -webkit-order: 2;
          order: 2;
         width:750px; 
       display:block; margin-left:114px;
      }

CENTER BOX
        #centerimage{-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
       -webkit-order: 1;
       order: 1}

RIGHT BOX
     #rightabout{
     -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
     -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
     -ms-flex-order: 3;
      -webkit-order: 3;
       order: 3;
       width:750px; display:block; margin-top:0px;background: white; 
        height: 450px; padding: 0px 0px 20px 20px; margin-left: 114px;
 }
```

Pseudocode HTML structure:

Header
CONTAINER row
     LEFT
     CENTER
     RIGHT

The appearance of the issue is as follows:

`[  gap] [ left box] [center image] [right box] [gap]`

here I want to remove [gap] in both left and right so that the left box and right box glue to the side of the mobile device screen.

Any advice and directions to remove the gaps would be greatly appreciated

Edit: here is JS fiddle demo to show what I meant about for demo purposes to show the gap instead it did not get the right side of flex to the device screen:
https://jsfiddle.net/martyforever/6bd9ca3y/

Comment: Can you create a small demo which shows what you have tried till now with the HTML structure?

Comment: @user1087834 It's not really clear what you are trying to do, but you should look into `justify-content: space-between;`;

Comment: @AKNair here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/martyforever/6bd9ca3y/

Comment: @fen1x I did try that but that did not solve the bug